# innerHTML aparece por un instante y luego desaparece

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando verificar un formulario e intento que usando un innerHTML coloque en un párrafo los errores que hubo pero el texto aparece y luego desaparece solo sale durante unos segundos, creo que se debe a que se recarga la pagina pero no se detener la recarga soy algo nuevo.
Mi código JS:

```
const name = document.getElementById('name')
const last = document.getElementById('lastname')
const email = document.getElementById('email')
const quest = document.getElementById('quest')
const form = document.getElementById('form')
const text = document.getElementById('warnings')

form.addEventListener("submit", e=>{
    e.defaultPrevented()
    let warnings = ''
    let send = false
    let regexEmail = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
    text.innerHTML = 'enviado'
    if(name.value.length < 3) {
        warnings += 'El nombre no es valido <br>'
        send = true
    } 
    if(last.value.length < 3) {
        warnings += 'El apellido no es valido <br>'
        send = true
    }     
    if(regexEmail.test(email.value)) {
        warnings += 'El email no es valido <br>'
        send = true
    }
    if(quest.value.length < 15 ) {
        warnings += 'Lo que sabes hacer es muy poco <br>'
        send = true
    }
    if(send) {
        text.innerHTML = warnings
    }
    return false
})
```

Y mi código HTML:

```
 <form id="form">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="nombre(s)" required><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="apellidos" required><br>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="correo electronico" required><br>
            <textarea id="quest" name="quest" rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="que sabes hacer..." required></textarea><br>
            <button class="boton-save">enviar</button>
          </form>
          <p id="warnings">

          </p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Lo que hace tu página es realizar el *submit* porque esta linea es incorrecta:

```
e.defaultPrevented()
```

Como puedes ver [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/defaultPrevented), el *defaultPrevented* devuelve verdadero o falso si es que ha sido llamado un *preventDefault* que es lo que necesitas establecer allí. Es decir, reemplaza esa línea por:

```
e.preventDefault()
```

Puedes mirar cómo funciona el *preventDefault* [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: Gracias Funciono!!